# Remove the space between images and get image tiles

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I tried different things but it doesn't seem to work. I am still learning bootstrap. I heard about removing the gutter but it hasn't worked when I tried. Here is what I am trying to achieve : http://designova.net/identity/index02.html and here is what I have currently: https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-thumbnail-gallery/#

Fiddle:

```
<div class="container" id="projects">
  <div class="row centered mt mb">
    <h1 style="font-family: 'Parisienne', cursive;  ">- Projects -</h1>

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 gallery" >
      <a href="work.html"><img src="assets/img/portfolio/folio01.png" class="img-responsive"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 gallery">
      <a href="work.html"><img src="assets/img/portfolio/folio02.png" class="img-responsive"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 gallery">
      <a href="work.html"><img src="assets/img/portfolio/folio03.png" class="img-responsive"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 gallery">
      <a href="work.html"><img src="assets/img/portfolio/folio04.png" class="img-responsive"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 gallery">
      <a href="work.html"><img src="assets/img/portfolio/folio05.png" class="img-responsive"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 gallery">
      <a href="work.html"><img src="assets/img/portfolio/folio06.png" class="img-responsive"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 gallery" >
      <a href="work.html"><img src="assets/img/portfolio/folio01.png" class="img-responsive"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 gallery">
      <a href="work.html"><img src="assets/img/portfolio/folio02.png" class="img-responsive"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 gallery">
      <a href="work.html"><img src="assets/img/portfolio/folio03.png" class="img-responsive"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 gallery">
      <a href="work.html"><img src="assets/img/portfolio/folio04.png" class="img-responsive"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 gallery">
      <a href="work.html"><img src="assets/img/portfolio/folio05.png" class="img-responsive"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 gallery">
      <a href="work.html"><img src="assets/img/portfolio/folio06.png" class="img-responsive"></a>
    </div>
  </div><! --/row -->
</div><! --/container -->
```

Comment: Please post a **minimal working example** of your code (HTML/CSS/JS) in a [Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See [mcve] and [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 : Remove margin-bottom of thumb class

```
.thumb{
    margin-bottom:0px;
}
```

Step 2: Override bootstrap styles

```
col-lg-3, col-md-4, col-xs-6{
   padding-right:0px;
   padding-bottom:0px;
}
```

Step 3: the anchor tag with class thumbnail has a margin-bottom of 20px, so remove it

```
.thumbnail{
    margin-bottom:0px;
}
```

after that it will look like this
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNW61.png)

Hope this helps ....

Answer (score 0):

You only have to remove the padding that's applied to your columns.

Adding this class to your `row` div. See [Attribute Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).

```
.no-gutter > [class*='col-'] {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

*Keep in mind this will only truly work as expected if all your images are the same size, otherwise you'll have an issue with the float applied to the columns created gaps inside the grid among other things.

Working Example: *Open with FullPage*

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.no-gutter > [class*='col-'] {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .gallery img {
    margin: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row no-gutter">

    <div class="col-sm-4 gallery">
      <a href="work.html">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/400/300/?gravity=center" class="img-responsive">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 gallery">
      <a href="work.html">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/400/300/" class="img-responsive">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 gallery">
      <a href="work.html">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/400/300/?gravity=east" class="img-responsive">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 gallery">
      <a href="work.html">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/400/300/?random" class="img-responsive">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 gallery">
      <a href="work.html">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/400/300/?gravity=west" class="img-responsive">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 gallery">
      <a href="work.html">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/400/300/" class="img-responsive">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 gallery">
      <a href="work.html">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/400/300/?random" class="img-responsive">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 gallery">
      <a href="work.html">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/400/300/?gravity=south" class="img-responsive">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 gallery">
      <a href="work.html">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/400/300/?random" class="img-responsive">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 gallery">
      <a href="work.html">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/400/300/?gravity=north" class="img-responsive">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 gallery">
      <a href="work.html">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/400/300/?random" class="img-responsive">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 gallery">
      <a href="work.html">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/400/300/?gravity=center" class="img-responsive">
      </a>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```